# Calculated column, if box is checked then date+6 month if not date+3 month

Tags: list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, date-time

I have a SharePoint list with 3 fields:

Date: the user enter the info
Prolongation: Checkbox
Second date: this is a calculated column.

This is what I want: if the "prolongation" box is checked, I want this field to show the 1st date + 6 months. If the box is not checked, I want the field to show date + 3 months.

I tried a few things but always get the error:

> Syntax error

Any idea/advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming "Prolongation" column is of type "Yes/No".

You can use below formula:

```
=IF([Prolongation], DATE(YEAR([Submitted]),MONTH([Submitted])+6,DAY([Submitted])), DATE(YEAR([Submitted]),MONTH([Submitted])+3,DAY([Submitted])))
```

Where `[Submitted]` is the display name of first date column.

**Sample output**:

[image]

**Note**: Make sure your first date column is required field. If it is not required, calculated column will show some random date value.

If first date column is not required field, you can use below formula:

```
=IF([Prolongation], IF(ISBLANK([Submitted]), "", DATE(YEAR([Submitted]),MONTH(Submitted)+6,DAY(Submitted))), IF(ISBLANK([Submitted]), "", DATE(YEAR(Submitted),MONTH(Submitted)+3,DAY(Submitted))))
```

**Sample output**:

[image]